# Receiving email to wildcard subdomain @ any alias (anyalias@*.domain.com)

Tags: smtp, email-server, wildcard-subdomain

I have seen lots of SaaS solutions provide client specific email URLs like the following: anyalias@*.mydomain.com.
This is a new concept to me but i need to adopt it for future application requirements. Few questions.

1. can i populate a "*.mydomain.com" MX record to push mail to ANY subdomain to a certain email host?  Will my existing domain.com MX continue as normal?
2. Is there an email server or hosted service that could function as a single "catch-all" mailbox.
   Then we would design an agent or service to parse the messages.

I am kinda stumped on this one so please contribute in any way even if it means asking a question!

Answer (score 2):

1) yes, this is possible (it actually depends on your dns server, but afaik most of them can handle wildcard records)

```
example.com   3600 MX 10 server1.example.com
*.example.com 3600 MX 10 server2.example.com
```

2) Accepting all subdomains is certainly possible with postfix, other MTAs probably as well.
Parsing messages (as in "read headers to get the recipient") is rarely a good idea, it's safer to filter based on the envelope recipient address. But it really depends on what exactly you are trying to do with those messages.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  The purpose is to serve as an input for DMS. The receive alias and sub-domain are metadata we can use within our application.